# What's the best way to fix two AngularJS directives with the same name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I have a project that's getting quite large. My problem is with clashing 3rd party  directives because of... unwisely... chosen directive names, i.e. "datepicker."

Since I use bower for dependency management, I don't want to edit any of the libraries because that would break portability.

How has anyone solved this issue?

Comment: What about putting them in different modules?

Comment: Thanks dustmouse, I clarified that I'm referring to 3rd party directives

Comment: A workaround could be that one is restricted in a different way than the other - one as attribute ('A'), the other as element ('E') - this could help differentiate? I am not sure if there is a solution for this.

Comment: @ItamarL. I get the feeling Angular would just use whatever one was defined last and throw an error if you tried to use it contrary to its `restrict` property

Comment: Not much you can do other than be highly selective about which modules you use

Comment: Might be able to accomplish this by manually bootstrapping more than one ng-app and separating the conflicting modules into those.  Pretty ugly though...  And you can't nest ng-apps, so if you need to use colliding directives together, it would still be an issue.

Comment: "How has anyone solved this issue?" By renaming their custom directives. Honestly, if the name is poorly chosen bite the bullet and fix the actual problem ;) The solution below mitigates the problem by chance, and doesn't guarantee that it won't happen again (if the 3rd party changes their code).

Comment: I acknowledge that it was luck already, but the only real solution is that those writing libraries follow the Angular team's advice and prefix the module and directive names appropriately.

Everything else is just a hack, and your solution breaks portability itself or requires foregoing automatic dependency management.

Lastly, the developers actually recently changed its directive names, prefixing them appropriately, and resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my comment, I created a plunker to see if this workaround is viable and to see how Angular behaves in the case of name clashing but under different modules:

http://plnkr.co/edit/9JKTEfGG4bu47QQIEhBh?p=preview

It seems that if you use different restrictions for different directives then it does work (you need to use the ones that are not mutual on the different directives).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

  <div some-directive></div>
  <some-directive></some-directive>

  <script>
    var myApp2 = angular.module('myApp2',[]);
    myApp2.directive("someDirective", function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'inside myApp2'
      };
    });

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp2']);
    myApp.directive("someDirective", function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: 'inside myApp'
      };
    });


  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
inside myApp
inside myApp2
```

Comment: Well, that's awesome! If the directive's `restrict` properties conflict, you might be able to change them with a decorator however you'll probably only be able to change the last registered one

Comment: Fantastic answer, directives have different access restriction levels. Since I'm referring to 3rd party libraries, it was luck that they have differing access restrictions.